# Measuring the time to create and destroy a simple object

Tags: java, time, object, measurement, finalizer

From Effective Java 2nd Edition Item 7: Avoid Finalizers

"Oh, and one more thing: there is a severe performance penalty for using finalizers. On my machine, the time to create and destroy a simple object is about 5.6 ns. Adding a finalizer increases the time to 2,400 ns. In other words, it is about 430 times slower to create and destroy objects with finalizers."

How can one measure the time to create and destroy an object?
Do you just do:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
SimpleObject simpleObj = new SimpleObject();
simpleObj.finalize();
long end = System.nanoTime();
long time = end - start;
```

Answer (score 2):

That only measures the time to execute the finalize method.  The vast majority of the cost of finalization will be in the special handling that the GC has to perform.

Comment: ok, what if I include Sytem.gc() just after simpleObj.finalize() above?

Comment: And the cycles spent making the GC more complex. You **can not** microbenchmark this.

Comment: @Tom Then how did Joshua Bloch measure the time stated in the book?

Comment: @portoalet I don't have the book with me. However, Josh has worked on Java at Sun and Google. I'm guessing there are some large systems to benchmark there. (NIO has finalisers removed in 1.4.1, IIRC, because they caused performance problems.)

Comment: hm ok, I guess I just have to ask Joshua how he did the measurement...The thing is I cannot find his email address?

Comment: From here: [http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references] this can be measured using a ReferenceQueue and a PhantomReference, but how to listen when something gets to ReferenceQueue? I don´t know

Answer (score 1):

Instead of futilely trying to microbenchmark this, as Tom Hawtin said above, the best approach is to examine the time to do a few hundred thousand cycles of creation and destruction, and divide by number of cycles.

This approach is the best in a lot of situations where the code you write is not the only code involved - where you're dependent on system calls, or external resources.

I think that's what Joshua Bloch did in this case, but my copy is upstairs and I'm feeling lazy.

Comment: well the book does not say how Josh does the microbenchmark. So basically you are saying put the code I have above in a for loop, and then average out the time?

Comment: Yup.  Do your best to exclude any other setup costs, classloading, etc (so for example, create and null a few instances before beginning the timing).

Comment: and how do you test the actual destruction of objects?? As far as I know the JVM specification doesn´t even push to implementations to finalize all objects, or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @jaime It's harder to do that (possibly impossible on individual objects) in a way that compares "with finalizer" against "without finalizer". But by doing many, many objects over a long period of time, the weight of the finalizer should become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You could request the Runtime to perform Garbage collection via [`Runtime.gc()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc()), but the Garbage Collector is not required to perform it right there and then:

- The [`finalize()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) method is not to be called by you, but by the Garbage Collector
- You could simply set the `simpleObj` to `null`, then call the Garbage collection to achieve a more realistic scenario

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to rely on the `java.lang.ref` package, which only supports a limited degree of interactions with the garbage collector.

The result of measurement couldn't be accurate, as it's hard to know the real ending of an object. I believe Joshua must have another approach to measure time, **maybe** head to JVM itself.

`PhantomReference` references nearest to end of life cycle of an object. In other words, the object is *phantom reachable*.

```java
public class WithoutFinalizationV1 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReferenceQueue<WithoutFinalizationV1> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
            
        PhantomReference<WithoutFinalizationV1> rf = new PhantomReference<>(
        new WithoutFinalizationV1(), queue);
        System.gc(); //advise JVM to do GC
            
        Object x = null;
        int waitCount = -1;
        do{
            x = queue.poll();
            waitCount++;
        } while(x == null);
            //only need this time point
        System.out.println("WithoutV1 "+ waitCount + " " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
    }
}
```

Run several times, the world record is 5394860ns, far from 5.6ns.

After adding

```java
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
}
```

the result is 5632208ns.

[Here](https://weiweitop.fun/2021/05/21/%E5%B0%9D%E8%AF%95%E6%B5%8B%E9%87%8FJava%E5%AF%B9%E8%B1%A1%E7%9A%84%E9%94%80%E6%AF%81%E6%97%B6%E9%97%B4/) is an extract from a related post I wrote.